# What is the difference between `get` (Debian's package manager) and a PPA?

Tags: apt, ppa

I understand that `apt-get` is Debian's package manager, based on the `apt` package manager (CLI) interface.

What is the difference between `apt-get` and PPA's?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not called `get`: [apt-get](https://wiki.debian.org/apt-get) is one of the many parts that make up [APT](https://wiki.debian.org/Apt) (advanced package tool).

A PPA is a personal package archive. It's a type of APT [repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) and a service where people can publish their own packages in addition to the ones that Debian and Ubuntu publish.